# Uncaught TypeError: Object false has no method 'css'

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a strange situation with a Web Application I am working with..all is working fine on my computer and in some others but, also if we use the same browser and same OS, someone got this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object false has no method 'css'
```

I can't debug it because I have no error :(

This is the [application](http://provinciaditerni.gfosservices.it/)

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error. It would seem like it is a caching issue.

Comment: Thx for your test. Can you confirm that you see colored points over the map?

Comment: I don't speak whatever that page's language is, so I can't really tell what is supposed to happen, but I see coloured points with numbers in them on the map. Tested with Chrome under Win XP.

Comment: Only managed to get errors like
`Image corrupt or truncated: http://tile.openstreetmap.org/6/38/21.png`
`Image corrupt or truncated: http://tile.openstreetmap.org/6/35/21.png`